# Smooth movement of icon displayed on a Panel

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-3.5, graphics

I'm coding an app where I display a System.Drawing.Icon object on a System.Windows.Forms.Panel using a code that goes something like so:

```
Graphics g = _panel.CreateGraphics();
g.DrawIcon(this.NodeIcon, _rectangle);
```

I have code to move the icon around using drag-n-drop.
My problem is that when the user move the icon around, it is anything but smooth.
The icon looks distorted until the user stops moving the icon.

I have tried to find information on this around the net but I can't get it to be smooth.
I have little previous experience of this particular kind of coding (using graphics) so I am a rookie to this.

If any kind soul could help me with some hints it would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have no idea as well, it seems while dragging, the redrawing algo is taking place and not very efficient.

Comment: I take it you've had similar problems?

Comment: @Freddy: Not really, that's my hunch :P

Comment: When I read "drag and drop," that has very specific connotations, but, as I read your question, I think you are referring to moving a graphic element around a panel, not "inserting" the icon into a control within the panel or moving it outside some control to the panel surface itself. Perhaps you can clarify exactly what you are doing, how you implemented "hit detection" on the icon.

Also : is just dragging a picturebox with an icon rendered in it an option using the standard over-rides for MouseDown, MouseUp, and MouseMove ? Hope these comments are helpful, best,

Comment: In general you shouldn't be using the Graphics object returned from CreateGraphics for anything but text measurement (Graphics.MeasureString). Rendering should happen in OnPaint.

Comment: Hit detection is performed in the MouseDown event just calculating if the MousePosition.X/Y is inside the icons boundaries. I have not tried using the PictureBox for this. I will try it. I need to read up on OnPaint and experiment more. Thank you all for your comments. When I've cracked I will let you know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you're trying to do is to redraw your control on the MouseMove event handler. And looks like your problem is the flicker when redrawing the panel. First what you can try to do is set true to [DoubleBuffered](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.doublebuffered.aspx) property of your panel. Doing this you would set the panel to redraw its surface using a secondary buffer to reduce or prevent flicker. This property is protected so you would need to create a new panel descendant:

```
public class TestPanel : Panel
{
  public TestPanel()
  {
     DoubleBuffered = true;
  }
}
```

as an alternative you can set the DoubleBuffered property for your panel through reflection

hope this helps, regards

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I will try this as well as the other tips from the other comments. When I've cracked the problem I will let you know.

Comment: Thanks! I finally had the time to test these tips and the DoubleBuffered did what I needed. Thanks again!