# DragDrop to move a picture box at run time

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a PictureBox called `pic`, placed inside another PictureBox called `picTrack`.

My goal is to be able to let the user, at run time, change the position of `pic` by draging it.

This is what I have so far:

```
    int x_offset = 0; // any better to do this without having a global variable?
    int y_offset = 0;
    void pic_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        PictureBox me = (PictureBox)sender;
        x_offset = me.Left - e.X;
        y_offset = me.Top - e.Y;
    }

    void pic_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            PictureBox me = (PictureBox)sender;
            me.Left = e.X + x_offset; 
            me.Top = e.Y + y_offset;
            picTrack.Invalidate();
        }
    }
```

This code only works at a very basic level. I have 2 problems with it:

1.) `picTrack` is not updated if the user does not let go of the mouse button. Ghost images of `pic` can be seen while `pic` is getting moved around (it's like `pic` is having a tail).

2.) `pic` is "giggling" (i.e. rapidly shaking left and right, up and down, around its location).

How should I solve these 2 problems and create a more smooth drag & drop? Thanks.

Comment: Could this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732890/smooth-movement-of-icon-displayed-on-a-panel

Comment: Do not use e.Button == MouseButtons.Left You should set a dragging boolean to true on MouseDown and false on MouseUp and check if(dragging) on mouse move.

Comment: Thanks @Alan. While we are at it, should I put `dragging` the same way I did `int x_offset = 0;`? It feels weird to have code outside functions somehow...

Comment: Perfectly normal, whenever I do dragging I usually have a dragPoint (for x,y) and dragging boolean outside my methods

Comment: When you are dragging something.. You can think of the drag as two snap shots... The rectangle where it was and the rectangle where it now is. You can invalidate those two rectangles on the parent control. Then you must call Update.

Comment: @user1032613 Did that work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here this actually works, I've written quite a few dragging things before.. it may not be perfect but this should give you something to work with.

```
    Point dragPoint = Point.Empty;
    bool dragging = false;

    private void pic_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        dragging = true;
        dragPoint = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
    }

    private void pic_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dragging)
            pic.Location = new Point(pic.Location.X + e.X - dragPoint.X, pic.Location.Y + e.Y - dragPoint.Y);
    }

    private void pic_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        dragging = false;
    }
```

See, if you were dragging a local picture that you were just rendering yourself, this wouldn't be right.. but since you are moving a **control** after you move it, the new move coordinates are relative to the control. Therefore, you do not need to update dragPoint to the last position on move. If you were just moving a shape/image you were rendering OnPaint, you'd have to do update the drag point each movement.

There's one improvement you could make, if desired, which is to only start dragging if the user moves the cursor a certain distance D. For example, something like this:

```
    Point dragPoint = Point.Empty;
    bool dragging = false;
    bool mouseDown = false;

    private void pic_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        mouseDown = true;
        dragPoint = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
    }

    private void pic_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        int deltaX = e.X - dragPoint.X;
        int deltaY = e.Y - dragPoint.Y;

        if (!dragging && mouseDown && deltaX * deltaX + deltaY * deltaY > 100)
            dragging = true;

        if (dragging)
            pic.Location = new Point(pic.Location.X + deltaX, pic.Location.Y + deltaY);
    }

    private void pic_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        dragging = false;
        mouseDown = false;
    }
```

Which checks if the user has moved the mouse 10 pixels (sqrt of 100).

If you don't want a global, you could try implementing your own behavior system and creating a reusable piece of code that you can attach to things you want to move. Something like this:

```
public class Behavior<T> where T : class 
{
    public T AssociatedObject
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public Behavior(T associatedObject)
    {
        this.AssociatedObject = associatedObject;
    }

    public virtual void Attach() { }
    public virtual void Detach() { }
}

public class DragBehavior : Behavior<Control>
{
    Point dragPoint = Point.Empty;
    bool dragging = false;
    bool mouseDown = false;

    public DragBehavior(Control c) : base(c)
    {

    }

    public override void Attach()
    {
        AssociatedObject.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(control_MouseDown);
        AssociatedObject.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(control_MouseMove);
        AssociatedObject.MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler(control_MouseUp);
    }

    private void control_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        dragging = false;
        mouseDown = false;
    }

    private void control_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        int deltaX = e.X - dragPoint.X;
        int deltaY = e.Y - dragPoint.Y;

        if (mouseDown && deltaX * deltaX + deltaY * deltaY > 100)
            dragging = true;

        if (dragging)
            AssociatedObject.Location = new Point(AssociatedObject.Location.X + deltaX, AssociatedObject.Location.Y + deltaY);
    }

    private void control_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        mouseDown = true;
        dragPoint = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
    }

    public override void Detach()
    {
        AssociatedObject.MouseDown -= new MouseEventHandler(control_MouseDown);
        AssociatedObject.MouseMove -= new MouseEventHandler(control_MouseMove);
        AssociatedObject.MouseUp -= new MouseEventHandler(control_MouseUp);
    }
}

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    DragBehavior dragger;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DoubleBuffered = true;

        dragger = new DragBehavior(pic);
        dragger.Attach();
    }       
}
```

Maybe that is better than "creating a global variable" (or more like creating a member variable in your form. =)

Comment: Based on your suggestion, I changed mine to `me.Left = me.Left + e.X - x_offset;` and it works great! Thank you. But I still don't understand why you don't need to update `x_offset` or "DragPoint" to the new position each time.

Comment: Let's say I was drawing a Rectangle on the OnPaint method. The distance dragged on each movement would be the difference between the current position and the last position. Each time it moves, I finish by updating the last position to the current.

However, In this case, you are moving an actual **Control**. When you move the control, the next move event is relative to the X,Y location of the control. So therefore, by moving the Control you are basically updating the absolute position of the DragPoint. The DragPoint is basically the X,Y position the cursor is at on the control while dragging.

Comment: If you were to convert the X,Y position from control coordinates to Screen Coordinates or Containing Form coordinates (e.g. pic.PointToScreen(p)), you'd have to update the last location on each move to find the difference. However, in your case, after you set your control location, your basically at a difference of 0 again!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
int x_offset = 0; // any better to do this without having a global variable?
int y_offset = 0;
private void pic_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   PictureBox me = (PictureBox)sender;
   x_offset = e.X;
   y_offset = e.Y;
}

private void pic_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
  {
     PictureBox me = (PictureBox)sender;
     me.Left = e.X + me.Left - x_offset;
     me.Top = e.Y + me.Top - y_offset;
   }
}
```

Comment: While it does not giggle nor leave ghost images any more, `pic` is not at where it's supposed to me. I don't understand why this stopped the giggling because in my opinion, `me.Left = e.X + me.Left - x_offset;` made `me.Left` ever-increasing. Say `Left` was `5` and `e.X - x_offset` is always `10`, `me.Left` would go to 5+10=15, then quickly go to 15+10=25, then 35, 45,... but in reality, it didn't ever-increase. It stopped quickly, at a wrong location.